# AWS SG self reference resolving different environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, aws-security-group

I want to make it more modular for different env (Dev,UAT, PROD) in that case i believe i should use  'name' of the SG("App${local.environment}sec_group") or only Sec_group?. here will it be able to resolve   source_security_group_id ? main.tf file:-

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sec_group" {
name   = "App${local.environment}sec_group"
vpc_id = "${local.vpc_id}"
} resource "aws_security_group_rule" "sec_group_allow_1865" {
type              = "ingress"
from_port         = 1865
to_port           = 1865 
protocol          = "tcp" 
security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sec_group.id}" 
source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.App${local.environment}sec_group.id}" ''' 
}
```

Variable.tf file:-

```
environment = "${lookup(var.ws_to_environment_map, terraform.workspace, var.default_environment)}"
vpc_id = "${lookup(var.ws_to_vpc_map, terraform.workspace, var.default_environment)}"
variable "default_environment" {
default = "dev"
}
variable "ws_to_vpc_map" {
type = "map"
default = {
dev = "vpc-03a05d67831e1ff035"
uat  = ""
prod = ""
}
}
variable "ws_to_environment_map" {
type = "map"
default = {
dev = "DEV"
uat  = "UAT"
prod = "PROD"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you could use

`source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.sec_group.id}"`

instead of

`source_security_group_id = "${aws_security_group.App${local.environment}sec_group.id}"`

aws_security_group.sec_group refers to the security group resource created with the name "sec_group"(resource "aws_security_group" **"sec_group"**) and aws_security_group.sec_group.id would get its id.